# How to fix the problem with dependencies in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I need the request to be made once, but an error related to dependencies appears. If I add to the dependency there will be an infinite loop.

What do you advise to do in this situation?

[image]

code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useObjects } from "../../store/api";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { GetObjectsAC } from "../../store/ObjectRecucer";
import { Object } from "./Object";

let MapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    currentObj: state.objReducer.CurrentObjects
  };
};
export let ObjectBlock = props => {
  const { request } = useObjects();
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = request("/api/objects").then(res => {
      props.GetObjectsAC(res.message);
    });
  }, []);
  const objBlock = props.currentObj.map((el, i) => (
    <Object key={i} street={el.street} home={el.home} />
  ));
  return <div>{objBlock}</div>;
};
export let ObjectContainer = connect(
  MapStateToProps,
  { GetObjectsAC }
)(ObjectBlock);
```

Comment: Move the effect logic inside it's parameterless function.

Comment: @ritaj The result is the same

Comment: Place `props.GetObjectsAC` inside the dependency array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will resolve the warning:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useObjects } from "../../store/api";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { GetObjectsAC } from "../../store/ObjectRecucer";
import { Object } from "./Object";

let MapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    currentObj: state.objReducer.CurrentObjects
  };
};
export let ObjectBlock = props => {
  const { request } = useObjects();
  const { GetObjectsAC, currentObj } = props; // destructure props
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = request("/api/objects").then(res => {
      GetObjectsAC(res.message);
    });
  }, [GetObjectsAC]); // Add value to deps array
  const objBlock = currentObj.map((el, i) => (
    <Object key={i} street={el.street} home={el.home} />
  ));
  return <div>{objBlock}</div>;
};
export let ObjectContainer = connect(
  MapStateToProps,
  { GetObjectsAC }
)(ObjectBlock);
```